# How to convert a summary output in a dataframe with headers in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a summary of variable, but I need to add a header in the new dataframe but I get an error.
My data:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3....
1    0    1
1    1    0
0    1    1
...

My code:
var=df[['Var1','Var2'....]].sum()

My output:
         0
------------
Var1    125
Var2    748
Var3    536
...

My expected output:
Type    Num
------------
Var1    125
Var2    748
Var3    536
```

But, when I add to my code: ,columns=['Type','Num'] an error appear. Someone could help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `Type` is an index, not a columns. You can either do

```py
var = var.reset_index()
var.columns = ['Type','Num']
```

or if you want to keep the index:

```py
var.rename({0: "Num"}, axis=1).rename_axis("Type")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfect!